# TensorFlow with Phonegap

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new into the ML Scene and I want to create a phonegap app involving Tensorflow but I'm unsure where to start or if this is even possible. Can anyone give me a hand (Probably by linking me to some resources)? My app will just use tensor flow image recognition (probably pre-trained).

Thanks, Felix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow is a tool to write computation using data flow graphs; this being said, if you want your app to use a pre-trained model only, there is no requirements to use TensorFlow specifically. You could even use one of the ML library written in Javascript to import and run the pre-trained model.

- Javascript DL libs: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/, https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet.js/
- TensorFlow for mobile: https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/
- Caffe Android: https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib
- DL4J Android: https://deeplearning4j.org/android